# Images not loading in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Tags: bug, images

I use Snow Leopard as my OS, I haven't been able to see embedded images in MSE for a month.

[image]

I deactivated all the extensions (because I looked on the Internet and many people had the same problem because of AdBlock) but still I'm not able to see them. Moreover if I copy the link of the image and paste it to see the image on stack imgur like here (i.stack.imgur.com/btAuw.jpg) the page won't load. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: PS, I added a image to my post, and can't see it :(

Comment: Of what is your image? All I see is a $34\times18$ black rectangle. However, [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/btAuw.jpg) load fine for me.

Comment: It sounds as if you are blocking or are blocked from imgur.com.

Comment: @robjohn I can see images from imgur, not from stack.imgur Yes, it's a small rectangle.

Comment: Just for information, I am running OS X 10.6.8, Snow Leopard, and Firefox 34.0.5, but I have not noticed any problems.

Comment: @robjohn I will try this (https://store.opendns.com/get/home-free) in a couple of hours and will tell you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @robjohn I changed my DNS, still can't connect to i.stack.imgur.com, bad luck I guess :( I'm contacting imgur now.

Comment: Any information from imgur.com? BTW, do you have a router that might be blocking i.stack.imgur.com?

Comment: @robjohn No info from imgur.com, I changed my router DNS as well, manually unlocked everything but I don't know why I can't see images from stack.imgur.com (from imgur.com I can).

Comment: I was going to suggest using direct IP addresses. i.stack.imgur.com is an alias for stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net which has 12 IP addresses. Unfortunately, Cloudflare requires a domain name in order to properly direct the request.

Comment: @robjohn Today I got some support from my internet provider. I'm not an expert in connections/computers. Do you have any website with instructions on how to use that direct  IP addresses you wrote about? The technicians that helped me today told me something similar.

Comment: You cannot use direct IP addresses with Cloudflare.  When the HTTP request comes in, they need to have the added information from the domain name (i.stack.imgur.com) to complete the reply.  This is the way things work when several domain names are handled through the same IP address. I tried using the direct IP addresses, and it doesn't work. You can try [this link](http://103.31.7.33/btAuw.jpg) and see the failure message.

Comment: @robjohn I can see images from ubuntu (in the same computer), not from mac.

Comment: Have you asked about this on SO? They might have some ideas there. Unless you have a software firewall for MacOS that is blocking images from stack.imgur.com, I can't think of anything else. Link each question to the other, so that people don't ask the same questions.

Comment: Make sure the image URL is http**s**. If StakExchange is using HTTPS, then it might back non HTTPS external images. StackExchange should make a bot that automatically changes non-HTTPS imgur.com URLs to HTTPS ones.