# Why images not displayed anymore?

Tags: bug, images

I have been using Math Stackexchnage site for several years. But from a few days ago I noticed that images cannot be displayed anymore.

[image]

I uploaded an image of what I see (I can't even see the image that I just uploaded!).

I'm using PC and Microsoft Edge browser. Am I the only one who has this issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: I we're talking about this post, I see a picture there: [Show that U,V and H are colinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4368047). Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYJzR.png). (And I also see the screenshot which [you included in this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSOr1.png).)

Comment: Can you see the images if you click on the links in my previous comments (or if you take the URL of the image from a post and just put it into the address bar of your browser)? Is it possible that imgur might be blocked by your employer or your Internet provider? (Something related to imgur being blocked was discussed in the comments here: [Images not loading in Chrome, Firefox and Safari](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19307). 
There is also this post on [meta.se]: [Hosting options for people that have Imgur blocked by their ISP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109975).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the guidance. No I can't see image you linked in the first comment.

Comment: @Martin, I see the image in the link of the question.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak I tried chrome browser and also used my phone but neither of them worked. But when I used VPN images are now visible! I'm living in Iran and we use VPNs for internet filtering, so should I always use VPN for seeing images?